# sshd and openssh server installation

Tags: software-installation, sshd

I'm new to Ubuntu. While installing hadoop I get port 22:conection refused. Then I found out that sshd and openssh server are missing. How to manually install these two? can I get a step wise answer?

Comment: Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html

Comment: I understood that you omitted asking how to set it up because it can be obvious but in that case add that to the question explicitly please.

Answer (score 0):

## Update list of packages

```
sudo apt-get update
```

## Install openssh server

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```